# R plot remove right margin

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a function that return a plot:

```
NDVI_Result = function(x,y){
output = raster::overlay(raster::raster(base::normalizePath(x)), 
raster::raster(base::normalizePath(y)), fun = NDVI)
graphics::par(bg=NA,mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(0,0,0,0))
raster::plot(output,axes=FALSE,box=TRUE,legend=FALSE, frame=FALSE)
```

After exporting this as png, I get this result:

[image: Result of exported PNG]

How can I remove the right margin of the result to be able to work with the image which then contains only the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `image` instead of `plot`

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
par(bg=NA,mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(0,0,0,0))
image(r, axes=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plot(...,legend.mar =  0)`.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.